# Setting content mode of UIButton not working in XCode6

Tags: uibutton, ios8, storyboard, uikit, xcode6

I have previously had no issue setting the content mode of a UIButton from the storyboard, I would just set the background image of the button and then under the view section I would set the mode to AspectFit or which ever mode was relevant.

When I try the above steps now in XCode 6 it makes no difference, the image remains scale to fill always.

I've also tried setting the default image instead of the background image and setting the content mode in code like this:

```
self.myButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

But it does not make a difference either, it remains scale to fill always.

Have apple changed the way this is done in XCode 6 or is this just a red herring and I'm missing something else?

Comment: Noticed this too, it's no doubt a serious pain. Pre-scaling the image does not feel quite right (since I want it to resize dynamically per device). One workaround is to subclass UIButton. Also, I think there is a `Image` and `Background Image` to UIButton, have you tried both?